# Как изменить стиль по условию отдельного элемента

Tags: angular

У меня есть клеточки, который выводятся на экран. У них всех есть значение true или false, которое прилетает с сервера. Изначально цвет коричневый. Я хочу, чтобы при клике, если клеточка false - она будет красной, а если true - зеленая. Вроде как нужно использовать [ngStyle] или [ngClass], но я не знаю как их прикрутить к клику, а не чтобы оно при загрузке страницы меняло все клеточки на соответствующие цвета, ибо нужно только по клику, только по отдельному одному элементу, где был клик.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

HTML:

```html
<div class="containers text-white">

    <div class="apple-grid" *ngFor="let rows of row.reverse(); let i = index;">

      <button 
              [disabled]="isDisabled[i][j]"
              (click)="btnClick(cols)"
              class="cell"
              *ngFor="let cols of rows; let j = index">
      </button>





    </div>

  <button (click)="start()">start</button>

</div>
```

TS:

```
  btnClick(cols:any)
  {
    if(cols)
    {
      cols.style("color:red")
    }
  }
```

Как можно реализовать это?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

делаете color[i][j] по аналогии с уже имеющимся у Вас isDisabled[i][j]
присваиваете color[i][j] нужный цвет и устанавливаете для тега

`[ngStyle]="color[i][j] ? ('color:'+color[i][j]) : ''"`

или

`style="{{color[i][j] ? ('color:'+color[i][j]) : ''}}"`

Причём, если задача клика мыши лишь окрасить кнопку, то функция необязательна.  Прямо в теге пишите

`(click)="{{color[i][j] = (cols ? 'green' : 'red');}}"`

ну а если хочется всё же функцией, то придётся передать в неё обе координаты.